# Put the facebbok php sdk sessions away from url

Tags: php, facebook, session, cookies

does anybody know, if there is any possibility to store the facebook php sdk sessions not directly in url? For example classic server side stored session with PHPSESSID cookie on client side..

I hate this nasty urls..:)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure here, but as far as I am aware when authenticated Facebook redirects to these 'nasty' urls containing the session ids. You can store the session from this redirected url, and then redirect to a cleaner url (removing session keys from it). The end user will not see the 'nasty' urls this way.